# Taking screenshots for Allure reports from custom TestNG listener - TestListenerAdapter

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, allure

I'm implementing custom test listener called **TestListenerAdapter** in my project and I wrote the code to capture screenshot in onTestFailure method of listener class. I also created following method and i'm calling in OnTestFailure method:

```
@Attachment(type = "image/png")
private byte[] createAttachment() {
    return ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
}

public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result)
{
  createAttachment();
}
```

The above method is not attaching the screenshots to Allure reports.

If we call createAttachment() method in @Test method then only screenshots are being added to allure reports.
Adding screenshot method in each and every @Test is hectic task, so i've implemented this method in TestNG listener so that screenshot is captured whenever a test case is failed.

Please let me know if there is a way to use above mentioned createAttachment() method from onTestFailure() method of TestListenerAdapter listener.

Comment: How are you add your listener to tests? Using SPI all works fine https://github.com/baev/allure-testng-example

Comment: Hi Charlie,
I'm calling created 'TestListener.java'(my listener class) class from TestNG.xml file. Please find the code below:
`<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="1" verbose="1" name="Gmail Suite" annotations="JDK" parallel="classes">
<listeners>
<listener class-name="com.listener.TestListener" />
</listeners>
<test name="RunTests">
<parameter name="browserType" value="firefox"/>
<classes>
<class name="com.testsuite.other.OtherLinks"/>
</classes>
</test>
</suite>`
We're using Ant to run the scripts and I'm calling TestNG.xml file from Build.xml file

Comment: However, below implementation worked for me.
Now, I'm calling listener class in my Actual testcase class using '@Listeners' annotation of TestNG.

    `@Listeners({ com.listener.TestListener.class})
    public class OtherLinks
    {
     **** code ****
    }`

if listener class calling from 'TestNG.xml' file is not yet implemented, then it can be taken as future improvement as we have to call @Listeners annotation in every testcase file.

Comment: I can't understand where is the problem. AspectJ behaves strangely. Seems like testNG use few threads to parse/process *testng.xml* configuration.

Comment: @Charlie So do you have to use SPI to load your listeners for them to work with Allure? Seems like this is the case.

Comment: @Conner could you please explain what are you mean?

Comment: @Charlie There are three ways to add TestNG listeners. 1) You can add them by adding the Listener annotation on the listener class. 2) You can add them in the testng.xml using the <listener> tag 3) You can add them using java's serviceloader (SPI).

Comment: @Charlie I do not wish to use the serviceloader(SPI) method for adding testng listeners but it seems to be the only way for this to work with Allure. I'm trying to take a screenshot on failure and I'd like to specify my listener in the testng.xml and not the serviceloader.

Comment: As I say before - I don't know why it is doesn't work with testng.xml. Could you please try to investigate the problem?

Comment: @Charlie Ok I will investigate. To get me started, would this be in the allure-testng-adaptor jar?

Answer (score 0):

For Allure listener to work with TestNG you have 2 options:

1. Use an annotation on your test class:

   ```
   @Listeners(MyAllureListener.class)
   public class MyTestClass() {
      ...
   }
   ```
2. Use [Java Service Provider Interface (SPI)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html) like this:
   [image]

filename has to match a listener `package.classname` that you extend. This file has to include a `package.classname` line pointing to your Listener class, i.e. `com.test.MyListener`